# Unable to change the workgroup of the server to domain name

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, domain-controller, nslookup, active-directory

I am unable to change the workgroup of the server to my domain name on the DC

The following is the error i get...

> Note: This information is intended for a network administrator.  If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\Windows\debug\dcdiag.txt.
>
> The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "core.com":
>
> The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
>   (error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)
>
> The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.core.com
>
> Common causes of this error include the following:
>
> - The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:
>
> 127.0.0.1
>   76.12.70.126
>
> - One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:
>
> core.com
>   com
>   . (the root zone)

I have entered made the DC as the prefered DNS server by entering its IP address on its NIC

```
C:\Users\Brett>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 202668-9
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-A0-22-50
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.12.48.X(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 76.12.48.100(Preferred)--set by me-->load balancing
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 76.12.48.X
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 76.12.70.126 -->DC's IP address
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Could you tell me what the problem could be?

Further logs from my investigation

```
C:\Users\Brett>nslookup core.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  76.12.70.126
Name:    core.com

C:\Users\Brett>nslookup
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  76.12.70.126

set q=srv
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.core.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  76.12.70.126

*** UnKnown can't find _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.core.com: Non-existent domain

C:\Users\Brett>dcdiag

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Trying to find home server...
   ***Error: 202668-9 is not a Directory Server.  Must specify /s:<DirectoryServer> or  /n:<Naming Context> or nothing to use the local machine.
   ERROR: Could not find home server.
```

P.S: The Active Directory Domain services on the server is stopped and i am also unable to start it.

I am into programming, this is my first attempt at any such task.  I hope to find some useful answers

Comment: Changing a workgroup name to the name of the domain. For why?

Comment: i want to implement load balancing feature for clients who use Remote desktop connections on access this server(there is one more server which is a clone of this one)

Comment: I just plain don't know how to say this nice, so I'm just going to say it.  The problem here is that you don't have even the slightest clue what you're doing.  This isn't the way you load balance RDS.  That's not the way you change a computer's workgroup.  That's not how you join a domain.  I can't even figure out what the heck you're trying to do here, but whatever it is, you're going about it wrong.  Time to go back to the drawing board, and/or get someone who knows what they're doing to set this up for you.

Comment: I totally understand you getting annoyed.. as i have mentioned, this is my first attempt at handling any server related work.. I do not have much of a clue about this.. I am doing this for a colleague, who is not here.. Sorry!.. Could you tell me if the idea of trying to Load balance with 2 web servers and a DC is right?

Comment: @user1751510  I'm not annoyed. I'm trying to say that you're just not going to be able to get help on this because your knowledge deficiency in this area is too large.  Like someone asking you how to create a Java module without knowing how to write code.  Even your question, `trying to Load balance with 2 web servers and a DC` doesn't make sense.

Comment: ohh, Sorry again.. Is there anything that i can do(willing to read up, throughout the weekend) to start working on this??.. My colleague cannot do this now.. I have to find my way through this...

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  You seem to be lacking fundamental knowledge in Windows domains, DNS and core networking concepts, and it's not really the *cram-for-one-weekend* kind of thing.  But if you're hellbent on trying anyway, I'd start with intro-level Windows and Windows domain administration.  Learn what AD is, the broad strokes of how it works, and how domain machines are different from workgroup ones... and see where that leaves you.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you load balance Remote Desktop services. There's a dedicated Windows Server role for that specific task: [Remote Desktop Gateway](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560672%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)